# selecting an element by name attribute from a specific divider in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to select an element that has name="load" 
I know i can do that by $('[name=load]'); in jquery
but i would like to select elements with name load only belonging to a specific divider 
with an id="usernameIn"

How would i go about selecting only the children of that divider  with a name load??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('#usernameIn').find('[name=load]');
```

Comment: why is using .find() better then other solution suggested is it simply because it looks neater? (im not saying that its not important)

Comment: @Xitcod13 Both should return same results but using `.find` should be little faster as `$('#usernameIn [name=load]');` internally would be doing the same.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('#usernameIn [name=load]');
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get elements contained in usernameIn:

```
$('#usernameIn [name=load]');
```

if you want direct children of usernameIn:

```
$('#usernameIn>[name=load]');
```

Answer (score 0):

to get element reside within `#usernameIn`

```
   $('[name=load]', '#usernameIn');
```